# How to use ExecuteScriptMarkLogic in processor in Apache NiFi?

Tags: marklogic, apache-nifi, marklogic-9

I am in midst of developing egress solution to pull out data from MarkLogic and sending to Kafka. For the same I am evaluating Apache Nifi. Marklogic does provide few processors for the same, but I am unable to find any example for **ExecuteScriptMarkLogic**. I am trying Execution Type **XQuery** and a simple script like fn:doc() or a query for a single file too. It keeps on increasing **Tasks** for the processor but nothing comes up in result.

Comment: Do you have a processor feeding into it? I'm looking at the code for it, and it expects a FlowFile to exist.

Comment: @rjrudin Indeed that was a missing link. But I feel it should not depend on input files, however worked for me. But, yes the results have wrong file name, same as input record, I shall file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @rjrudin ExecuteScriptMarkLogic relies on input flow-file.

So if you are trying to query using a custom script use Generate flow-file processor.

Comment: Yet, I have not been able to pass a value to ExecuteScriptMarklogic so that the Script Body code can act on some input value from another processor upstream. I have tried flowfile-attribute and flowfile-content from an EvaluateXQuery/EvaluateXPath Processor into the Content Variable property but no cigar. An example would be helpful.

Comment: Looking at the code, Content Variable is for output from the script. Using an attribute from upstream processor called name (which is successfully being set), I execute this in the Script Body: `let $first-name := ${name} return $first-name`. I get a null error.

Comment: Alright, solved the problem. Cannot assume the processor knows the attribute value is a string. So, this worked: `let $first-name := '${name}' return $first-name`.